# How to render basic HTML code with html elements in a view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am having a form html as follows:

```
<div class=\"container\">\r\n\t<div class=\"clearfix row
\">\r\n\t\t<div class=\"col-md-12 column\">\r\n\t\t\t<h3>\r\n\t\t\t\tNew form created\r\n\t\t\t<\/h3
>\r\n\t\t\t<div class=\"form-group\">\r\n\t\t\t\t <label><strong>Enter   name<\/strong><\/label><input
name=\"1430985388220267#enter_name\" id=\"1430985388220267\" class=\"form-control\" grid-name=\"Enter
 name\" type=\"text\" \/>\r\n\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t<\/div>\r\n<\/div>
```

This form i want to display in mobile app. The mobile app i have developed in ionic framework and cordova with angular JS. When i am trying to show the form as html then it is getting rendered with basic elements like header, bold, labels like content but the input tag it is not showing or else i can say the html's basic data input elements like checkbox, radio button etc are not displayed. I am doing this in the view:

```
<ion-view title="Fill the Form">
<ion-content class="padding-vertical" ng-repeat="htmlValue in HTML">
<div ng-bind-html="getHtml(htmlValue)">

</div>
{{htmlValue}}
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

my getHtml function is this:

```
    $scope.getHtml = function(html){
        var trusted = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
        return trusted;
    };
```

i have also modified:

```
angular.module('iot', ['ionic','chart.js','ngSanitize'])
```

I am pushing the code from REST response into array called `HTML`

but still i am not getting the expected output what else has remained in this case? Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: What do you see? Any error in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use filter:

```
// Filter to enable HTML tags
app.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

Then include this within your HTML tag along with filter ('unsafe' in this case), for example:

```
<!-- i.detail will be your valuable -->
<div ng-bind-html="i.detail | unsafe"></div>
```